# Syntax for implementing a protocol in Objective C, as compared to C#?

Tags: c#, objective-c

Unexpected events at my company have resulted in my being drafted in to write and release an iphone app in a short amount of time, though I have no experience in Objective C. I'm having trouble following some of the syntax:

I have the following method definition:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

It lives in a class that is defined with this interface:

```
@interface TableExampleViewController : UIViewController 
    <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSArray *lightbulbs;
}
```

What does the method declaration mean? I understand that `UITableViewCell *)` is the return type, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is the method name, and `(NSIndexPath *) indedPath` is the parameter, but what is the significance of `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView`? I assume it has something to do with the protocols that the class implements. What would be the equivalent syntax in c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Objective-C method name includes all argument names, so the name of the method is

```
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

which includes both colons `:`.

It has nothing to do with protocol implementations - it is simply the way the methods are named in Objective-C. So an imaginary C# equivalent would be simply

```
UITableViewCell tableViewcellForRowAtIndexPath(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
```

Comment: Having learned Objective-C on top C# myself, I can attest to the syntax feeling strange for the first few months. It is very important to pay attention to colons, especially when you get into selector area.

Comment: I learned oc after c# also. and We come up almost the same answer. Interesting. :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks for your answer. It look pretty weird! I thought it wouldn't be too bad as its a superset of C, but the messaging system is strange.

Comment: @Oliver By the way, the closest thing related to parameter naming of Objective-C in C# would be invocations with named parameters: `tableViewcellForRowAtIndexPath(tableView:tableViewObj, indexPath:myIndexPath)`, except unlike C#, you cannot switch the parameters around in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

```
tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

is the method name,  it different from c#'s naming. in c#, the method definition might be

```
UITableViewCell GetCellFromTableViewAtIndexPaht(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the Delegate Design Pattern. Basically the UITableView instance in your UIViewController class asks your view controller to provide a UITableViewCell for the specified index. So let's say you have an array of songs in your view controller and you want them to appear in the table view. Then you would create a new UITableViewCell, set it's textLabel.text to the title of the song at the specified index (indexPath.row) and return the cell. Because you are supposed to reuse UITableViewCells for performance reasons, I recommend reading the Table View Programming Guide in the documentation, especially [Populating a Table View](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW11)